# SQL Sub query doubt

Tags: sql, subquery

i'm a bit stuck and would appreciate the help..... i'm sure i need to use a sub query but when i try i m getting errors saying returning more than one row....

So this is the code

```
SELECT to_char(p.releasedate, 'YYYY') AS releaseyear , t.genre
, COUNT(*) AS "Number of awards"
FROM dbf11.film p
JOIN dbf11.genre t
ON p.filmID = t.filmID
GROUP BY p.releasedate, t.genre
ORDER BY p.releasedate, t.genre ;
```

What i'm trying to do is.... for each year display the no. of films for each genre

What i'm currently getting is

```
2010 Action 1
2010 Comedy 1
2010 Comedy 1
2011 Action 1
2011 Action 1
2011 Action 1
```

What i want it to display is

```
2010 Action 1
2010 Comedy 2
2011 Action 3
```

Comment: Can you post the sub-query you're attempting to use?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
SELECT to_char(p.releasedate, 'YYYY') AS releaseyear, 
    t.genre.
    COUNT(*) AS "Number of awards"
FROM dbf11.film p
INNER JOIN dbf11.genre t ON p.filmID = t.filmID
GROUP BY to_char(p.releasedate, 'YYYY'), t.genre
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
ORDER BY to_char(p.releasedate, 'YYYY'), t.genre;
```

Comment: another thing... what if i wanna display only genre's which have more that 1 release....

Comment: Thanks.... i forgot bout having count.... i kept trying it with count(*) > 1.....

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT to_char(p.releasedate, 'YYYY') AS releaseyear , t.genre
, COUNT(*) AS "Number of awards"
FROM dbf11.film p
JOIN dbf11.genre t
ON p.filmID = t.filmID
GROUP BY to_char(p.releasedate, 'YYYY'), t.genre
ORDER BY releaseyear, t.genre
```